# OpenMP does not provide speedup for simple program

Tags: openmp

I just started learning OpenMP with C++, and I used a very simple program to check if I can get some speedup from parallelize the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "omp.h"


int main() {
    const uint N = 1000000000;
    clock_t start_time = clock();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (uint i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int x = 1+1;
    }

    clock_t end_time = clock();
    std::cout << "total_time: " << double(end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds." << std::endl;
}
```

The program takes 2.2 seconds without parallel #pragma, and takes 2.8 seconds with parallel #pragma 4 threads. What mistake did I make in the program? My compiler is clang++ 6.0, and the computer is Macbook Pro with 2.6G i5 CPU and MacOS 10.13.6.

EDIT:

I realized I used the wrong function for measuring execution time. Instead of clock() from library ctime, I should use high_resolution_clock from library chrono library. In that case, I get 80 seconds for 1 thread, 47 seconds for 2 threads, 35 seconds for 3 threads. Should the speedup be better than what I get here, since the program is embarrassingly parallel?

Comment: Did you compile that with optimisation cranked to the max ?  I'm surprised the code took any time to execute, a decent optimising compiler would see that the entire loop is dead code (the results are not used) and optimised it into oblivion.

Comment: In addition, use omp_get_wtime() instead of clock to measure the time. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777810/c-omp-omp-get-wtime-returning-time-0-00)

Comment: Unless you have a NUMA platform, e.g. dual CPU, even a single thread could consume the full memory bandwidth.  Without OpenMP, a full optimizing compiler (if it didn't eliminate the non-parallel loop as dead code) would likely substitute a memset call which automatically shifts to non-temporal stores, so that you don't need to read memory before storing.  It's not clear whether using uint in place of int may hinder optimization (almost certainly a problem if using 32-bit mode).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sure, if any optimization is used then the code takes no time, but I just want the code to do something inside the loop, so no optimization is used in this test. Shouldn't I get linear speedup with the number of threads used (given I have enough CPU) in that case??

Answer (score 0):

As with anything in parallel programming, there is a startup cost to creating new threads. For simple programs, the overhead of creating and managing threads is often great enough that it actually slows down the target program compared to when the program is run in a single thread.

In other words, you didn't make a mistake - this is an inherent part of using threads.

Comment: I increased the total number of iteration, so each thread should have enough work that the startup cost is negligible. The single-thread execution is 20 seconds and the 4-thread execution is 27 seconds. Your explaination here still does not explain what I observed.